# Integer array as type parameter in list in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, object, collections

How do I get the values from the list object if the list type parameter has int[] in java. So guys please help to fix this. I'm tried myself. But I stuck somewhere.

public class Stack {

```
public static int[] Varun = {94, 97, 21, 71, 80};
public static int[] Monti = {95, 90, 11, 80, 81};
public static int[] Shalini = {90, 91, 20, 71, 72};
public static int[] Kuldeep = {78, 77, 18, 90, 92};
public static int[] Arun = {71, 71, 21, 78, 98};
public static String[] performanceParameters = {"Creativity", "Communication", "TechnicalSkills", "PersonalHabits", "TakeInitiative"};
public static int[] attendenceList = {21, 11, 20, 18, 21};

public static ArrayList<int[]> parameters = new ArrayList<int[]>();

public String[] topPerformers(String[] listOfEmployees, List<int[]> parameters) {
    Arrays.sort(listOfEmployees);
    for(String a:listOfEmployees)
   {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
   Integer a[]=(Integer[]) parameters.toArray(new Integer[parameters.size()]);
    Iterator<int[]> it=parameters.iterator();
    for(int[] arr: parameters)
    {
       for(int item:arr)
       {
           System.out.println(item);
       }
   }

    Iterator<int[]> it = parameters.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        int[] arr = it.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
   // System.out.println(parameters.indexOf(this));

    String topPerformers[] = new String[3];
    Map m = new HashMap();
    // m.put(listOfEmployees, parameters);
    // write your code here.

    return topPerformers;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    parameters.add(Varun);
    parameters.add(Monti);
    parameters.add(Shalini);
    parameters.add(Kuldeep);
    parameters.add(Arun);
    Stack s = new Stack();
    s.topPerformers(performanceParameters, parameters);
}
```

Just give me the way to get the array elements from the list object. I'm tried but I'm doing something wrong. Just help to finish this. Thank You in advance.

Comment: An Integer[] array store Integer instances. Your list doesn't contains Integer instances. It contais int[] instances. So the line `Integer a[]=(Integer[]) parameters.toArray(new Integer[parameters.size()]);` doesn't make sense. Transforming a list of int[] to an array will can you an int[][], but not an Integer[]. But I have no idea what this method is supposed to do anyway, so you need to clarify your question.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with snippet? Each item within `parameters` is an int array.

Comment: What is in the `parameters` variable and what are you trying to do with it?  What's the expected result and what's the observed result?  It's not clear from this function what your goal even is here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this,

```
for(int[] arr : parameters){
      for(int item:arr){
           System.out.println(item);
       }
 }
```

Comment: Hi Kajal, It didn't work. Now I uploaded my entire code. Just take a look.

Comment: What was the error you getting??

Comment: Hi Kajal, your code is also working! I tried again by creating a new class and tried this separately. Its working! Thank You! You saved my time. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. Consider up voting the answer.

Comment: Kajal, one more help can you get the top 3 performers from that given program. If possible just ping me so I can do another one.

Comment: Two things, one, how you find the best performer? Two,  why don't you  use class performance with attributes creativity, communication etc. My suggestion is to create a class Performance with fields name, creativity, etc. And create a method getPerfoanceValue() which returns a numeric value based on your conditions and calculations. . And find the top three.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `next()` method in your iterator `it` to get an `int[]` instance and iterate over it like this

```
while (it.hasNext()) {
  int[] arr = it.next();
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: It works fujy thank You! You saved my time! thanks a lot.